# Neo4j - read and save data

Tags: neo4j

I've got problem with Neo4j.

First of all, I've got pieace of code:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("neo4j-store");

// creating some nodes, relationships and commiting transactions
```

but I can't find that datas in:
    http://localhost.pl:7474/webadmin 
... why?

And on the other hand. When I create some data via webadmin I can't read it from my java application. Why?

Comment: If your code shows one unique set a data, and the web admin tool shows a completely different set of unique data, I can't think of any other explanation than that you're pointing to two different databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web console pulls from where the neo4j is installed/run from. So it's usually `{neo4j.home}\data\graph.db` which your example there will create a DB at `./neo4j-store`. The easiest way to solve this is to set the `org.neo4j.server.database.location` in the `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file to point to where `neo4j-store` is. For me check [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can look at the webadmin configuration tab and look at the location of the database, and make sure your embedded program is using the same.